# SonarQube migration script #1908 runs forever (DeletePersonAndFileMeasures)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I'm trying to upgrade SonarQube from latest 6.7.1 version to 7.0. We are using Oracle. The database script "#1908 'Delete person and file measures'..." runs forever.

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/c0d2705e610d771b8c66ef22e64530c7bca4f538/server/sonar-db-migration/src/main/java/org/sonar/server/platform/db/migration/version/v70/DeletePersonAndFileMeasures.java#L49-L56

We have 4874 rows in the snapshots table and 12.8 million rows in the project_measures table. In the projects table we have 350.000 rows.

Anybody experienced this ??

Answer (score 0):

Slowness of this DB migration has been fixed in 7.1: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10504. Note that this version has not been released at the time of writing. It's planned for middle of April.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-) We cannot wait until mid april as our production instance has been migrating for a day now. Is it possible to build this change ourselves from source: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/commit/899f67cdb2937a8d209be318ef7caa2a2fdc0cf6 and then put this into production ?

Comment: We have approach 5000 snapshots and 499 are migrated after 20 hours....

Comment: I can only recommend using official releases.

Comment: Our migration in production has run for 7 days now..... Please release SonarQube 7.1 asap :-)

Comment: planned for Monday 16th April